# The parameter kl_use_exact in DenseVariational layer of TF

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability, densevariational

Trying to create a Bayesian neural network using DenseVariational layer in Tensorflow probability. My question is when we set the parameter kl_use_exact to False does by that we are not taking the prior function into consideration. I tried to look at the source code of the DenseVariational class (_make_kl_divergence_penalty function) and I'm more confused then before, I didn't get the use of kl_use_exact.

Comment: `kl_use_exact` specifies the calculation method of KL-Divergence between variational posterior and prior. `False`: Approximate // `True`: Actual value.

Comment: Thanks. With False, KL will be approximated by Monte Carlo sampling. Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: Added it with some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kl_use_exact` specifies the calculation method of KL-Divergence between variational posterior and prior.

`False`: KL will be approximated.

`True`: Uses the actual KL value. However it can be set `True` if and only if the KL-Divergence between the distributions are registered in TensorFlow-Probability.